# json format requirements for markers in google maps

Tags: json, google-maps, jquery

I have a json file like: `{ total: 86, success: true, "rows": [ {"a1_id":"3231VB8",` etc. etc.

My problem is that when using jquery for entering markers in google maps from eg this json file, it won't do so until I replace `<total: 86, success: true, "rows":>` by `<"markers":>` at the start of the json file.

Ok no problem doing that, but when I do so another json requests from the same url/file is broken.

Question: how should I deal with this? Is there a way to change the gmap code to deal with my json file or sh:

```
function(data) { 
    $.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.latitude, m.longitude), 'bounds':true } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially you're asking how to rename the "rows" property from the JSON to be "markers", because "markers" is what is used by that particular pieces of JS/jQuery code? And you need the change to be in that code so that the existing JSON can be used as is by other processes?

If so, why not just make the following small change in your JS/jQuery code to reference the "rows" property instead of "markers":

```
...
    $.each( data.rows, function(i, m) {
...
```

The only change is to the first parameter passed to `$.each()`. The "total" and "success" parameters from your JSON don't actually need to be removed because they are simply ignored by the code you've shown (both before and after my change).

If for some reason you need to actually modify the `data` object, which I assume was created by parsing the JSON, you can try something like this:

```
    data = { "markers" : data.rows };
```

That is, create a new object that has a single property, "markers", which references the "rows" array from the original object, and then re-assign the `data` variable to point to the new object. Then simply use your `$.each()` as is.

Comment: "The "total" and "success" parameters from your JSON don't actually need to be removed because they are simply ignored by the code you've shown (both before and after my change)"; that's what I thougt but your first and second solution only work for me when deleting the "total" and "succes" parameters. Otherwise; no gmap shows up. It's all white. I was also surprised by this behaviour. Any clue?

Comment: Well it could be because your JSON file isn't actually valid JSON: property names must be quoted, so your "total" and "success" properties should have double-quotes around their names. Try changing that.

Answer (score 0):

After using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate my JSON output, I received the suggestion to add quotes around the strings "total" and "success". So I did and the JSON output validates correctly.

This resulted in ExtJs as well as Google Maps accepting my JSON file.

To keep in mind: if one application is accepting your JSON (ExtJs), that won't say the other does too. (Google Maps).

Comment: Sure, that's what I mentioned in my comment yesterday. Without the quotes it is definitely invalid JSON, but depending on how it is parsed it may work anyway (e.g., if your app is just `eval`ing it it would likely still work since it is valid JavaScript syntax even without the quotes).